# How can I ensure that all submodule commits referenced by a git superproject are valid (and stay valid)?

Tags: git, bitbucket

As a developer I have a superproject that uses a submodule.
I can configure git to ensure that commits to the superproject have valid submodule references at the time of pushing them (`git config push.recurseSubmodule check`).

**Can I configure git/BitBucket to ensure that gitlinks referenced by my superproject will always exist in the submodule?**

In particular, I am concerned about the following scenario:

- a developer pushes a submodule commit to a feature branch
- a developer pushes a superproject commit that references a commit the submodule feature branch

  - *the push to the superproject is allowed by the config as the gitlink is currently valid on the remote*
- a developer subsequently *removes* the submodule feature branch without merging it

  - *the superproject is now broken: it has a gitlink to a commit that does not exist in the remote*

I need to retain control over what is referenced in the superproject (I don't want to automatically follow a branch on the submodule).

Potential approaches:

1. Is there any way with git or BitBucket to enforce that the superproject can only contain submodule gitlinks that are on the submodule master branch?
2. Is it possible to enforce that any PR merges in the superproject only contain commits where the gitlinks resolve against the submodule master branch?
3. ... or some better approach here that I'm not seeing at all?

Side note: I've attempted to go through the process to break the superproject, but it didn't work! I think that this is because the SHA of the feature branch on the remote is not immediately cleaned away (reflog default pruning strategy is to keep 90 days history).

Answer (score 1):

Just keep your own copy of the needed commits, keep a bitbucket fork or a local clone or whatever, with tags for the referenced commits.

---

As an academic exercise, if you were using Git and not bitbucket to do your merging, the checks would be like five lines of hook,

```
git rev-list ..MERGE_HEAD` | xargs -rn1 git ls-tree -rd \
| awk '$2=="commit" {print $3}' | sort -u
```

to show you every merged submodule commit, and

```
[[ `git for-each-ref --count=1 ---format=ok  --contains $commit \
        refs/remotes/origin/{master,stable}` = ok ]]
```

to check whether `$commit` is in origin's last-seen master or stable histories, so a minimum-viable-smoketest for what you're after would be

```
for commit in $(git rev-list ..MERGE_HEAD` | xargs -rn1 git ls-tree -rd \
                | awk '$2=="commit" {print $3}' | sort -u); do
        [[ `git for-each-ref --count=1 ---format=ok  --contains $commit \
                refs/remotes/origin/{master,stable}` = ok ]] || die "Commit $commit is not published"
done
```

`push.recursesubmodules check` does pretty much exactly this, only without the specific remote and tracking restrictions

---

A note:

Common practice I'm familiar with has been to distinguish administrative status by repo residence, the QA team tends to run an ~incoming~ repo to which devs or review teams push commit series for integration, and the production team likewise will have a repository for code pushed into production, and so on. That way each team can trust people they know personally and do any automated vetting of inbounds in the pre-receive.  All publishing repos really should be running sanity-tests on inbounds, and things like the above would be good candidates.

Comment: That would be perfect for a personal project! In this case I’m configuring a repo for a team, and I’m trying to ensure that multiple developers can use it all safely without manual oversight required...

Comment: Either you rely on the upstream to not abandon history, or you administer your own repo. What to keep in your repo is an administrative choice., and Git doesn't give you the option of forcing administrative choices on other people's repositories.

Comment: In this specific case both repositories are mine. I *think* I want a BitBucket check when pull requests are merged to master in the superproject to ensure that all dependencies are present in a specified branch of the submodule ('master' or 'stable', etc). This approach wouldn't force any choices on the configuration of the submodule in the event that it was someone else's respository. BitBucket doesn't seem to support this yet which surprised me since it feels like a fairly generic problem.

Comment: What's wrong with a ~blessed~ or ~published~ or whatever you want to call it repository to which only such histories are ever pushed? Anything there is safe, and that's what others refer to.

Comment: Fair point! In this case a large team of developers will be committing to both superproject and submodule repositories. I can't afford to become a manual gatekeeper. Something like this: https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/bitbucket-submodule-safe-hook/src/master/ *almost* does what I want, except (1) I need to ensure that the submodule updates are in master rather than generically 'available on the remote' and (2) the check needs to be at PR merge time rather than on push.

Comment: Can you explain your (1) requirement in more detail ? (please add it to your question)

Comment: The requirement (1) in the above comment is a detail of a specific implementation rather than a key part of the problem. I'd rather not add it to the question as I don't want to bias people with a particular approach! The problem of (1) is that `git config push.recurseSubmodule` only checks that the submodule reference dependency is available on the remote (maybe a short-lived 'test' branch that will be thrown away) and does not guarantee that the dependency is on master, or any other stable branch.